# How to fix syntax error of create samples command in OpenCV

Tags: python, macos, opencv, terminal

I'm trying to create samples using the opencv_createsamples command on terminal in MacOS, but when I try to this, it gives "SyntaxError: invalid syntax"

My code is;

opencv_createsamples -img resized_sample_1.jpg -bg bg.text -vec info -maxxangle 0.5 -maxyangle 0.5 -maxzangle 0.5 -num 1000

I think the command create_samples is not defined but I should have installed all the necessary packages.

Thank you!

Comment: It is a bit of a generic error code. Is there any more error output in the terminal? That could help us limit the scope of the problem?

Comment: No, the only output is the "invalid syntax". But when I type just "opencv_createsamples", it says command not found.

Comment: Aha. What if you try this: /opt/local/bin/opencv_createsamples .Or with another path if that did not work

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are facing might be because you have not build the opencv_createsample from its source since it doesn't come with the package.
The only solution is that you have to build opencv_createsample from (https://github.com/opencv/opencv/tree/master/apps) here, unfortunately.
Hope you got what you were looking for :)
If you are facing issue still then drop a comment.

Comment: Thank you for your response! I have cloned the repo in the same directory but it still doesn't work.. Do I have to build it somehow?

Comment: well, you clone the github repo, then build the opencv libs (& apps) using cmake, and then you can run those tools.